# How to achieve two rows in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I want put one TextView at left upper corner(0,0), one TextView at right upper corner(0,1) and LinearLayout  below at the bottom (1,0 and 1,1). I tried like

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rlHeader"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtLowerBound"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text=" "    
>
</TextView>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtUpperBound"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>
</TextView>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llRatingNumbers"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_below="@id/txtUpperBound"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
></LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

but it displays all in one row. What to change to have two rows, in upper two TextViews and in the lowetr LinearLayout ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llRatingNumbers"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@id/txtUpperBound"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
></LinearLayout>
```

try this for your linearLayout.

Comment: this will not place the linearLayout at the bottom , you should use alignParentBottom ="true" , or layout_bellow="@id/txtLowerBound"

Comment: the OP question was 2 rows, one below another, i think my layout exactly fits that purpose. care to explain why android:layout_below="@id/txtUpperBound" will not work?

Comment: now i'm agree, there is the attribut ( layout_below ) , so there is no need of alignParentLeft :)

Comment: i'm not saying that, but at the first time  you didnt add the layout_below , the second thing ,after that you have added the attribute layout_below , so the other attribut alignParentLeft has no need to add it , it will change anything , so delete it :) , and calm down man ^^

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtLowerBound"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text=" "    
>
</TextView>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtUpperBound"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/txtLowerBound"
>
</TextView>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llRatingNumbers"
    android:background="#FF55AD"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="85dp" //just for example 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
></LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

i dont know if you want your `linearLayout` at the bottom of your textView ( if you want that your layout be under the textviews , so change the attribut : `alignParentBottom` with `android:layout_below="@id/txtUpperBound"` ) , or at the bottom of your Screen ( in my answer ,the `linearLayout` will be at the bottom of your screen ) ,